# Must this sentence be a tautology?

Tags: logic

**Suppose that P is the only sentence letter that appears in $\phi$1 and that $\phi$1 is neither a tautology nor a contradiction. Suppose that the same is true of $\phi$2, *i.e.* P is the only sentence letter that appears in $\phi$2 and $\phi$2 is neither a tautology nor a contradiction.**

**Must the sentence ($\phi$1 $\leftrightarrow$ $\phi$2) $\vee$ ($\phi$1 $\leftrightarrow$ ¬$\phi$2) be a tautology?**

I believe it must be a tautology as under any structure *A* that assigns a truth-value to P, $\phi$1 and $\phi$2 would have the same truth-value and therefore ($\phi$1 $\leftrightarrow$ $\phi$2) would be a tautology. With the disjunction $\vee$, the entire sentence would then be a tautology.

Am I misinterpreting what it means to have P as the "only sentence letter that appears in $\phi$1"? I might be overthinking the question.

Comment: Yes, since $$(P\leftrightarrow Q)\lor (P\leftrightarrow \lnot Q)$$ is a tautology.

Comment: What do you mean by $\phi_1$ is *neither a tautology or a contradiction*? Which system of logic are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how $\phi_1$ or $\phi_2$ are defined, remember that $\neg(a \iff b)$ is the same as $\neg a \iff b$, or equivalently (without loss of generality), $a \iff \neg b$, for any statements $a$ and $b$. Thus, what we have is a

$$r\vee\neg r$$

situation. Which is a tautology if we assume the [Law of Excluded Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle), as is classically standard. Where, $r$, in this case is $\phi_1\iff\phi_2.$